# How Can I rewrite SEO friendly URL on STRUTS?

Tags: java, seo, struts, friendly-url

We have a website which is coded Java with Struts Framework. The WebSite's Urls are not seo friendly. All of them are like below

> ../buyerApplication.do&companyId=2323

Now We want to make these URLs SEO friendly and I searched and found these solutions:

- tuckey.org/urlrewrite : but i don't rely on this system.
- adding
  title end of link after '&' such as
  "../newsId=33233&does-art-in-the-city-equal-art-for-the-city"
  : In this solution I am not sure it
  works well.

I am waiting your sugestions to solve this problem best.

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest to read *Dynamic URLs vs. static URLs* on the Google Webmaster Central Blog (http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the point, you need a Filter for this.

If you want to keep your existing application's architecture, you'll need to define and create a set of rules to convert unfriendly urls to friendly urls and let the filter convert it and **forward** the request to the unfriendly url.

If there is no means of modifying an existing application but you want to create a new application based on this idea, you could consider to having a single page controller which translates the HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()/getRequestURI() to execute the appropriate action class (command pattern) and finally forward the request to the appropriate JSP page. Not sure how that would fit into Struts as I haven't worked with Struts previously.

Answer (score 2):

I actually used URLRewriter (http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), which you referenced in your original question.   It was very easy to set up  and filled my needs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you can also look at the REST plugin http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html, which amongst other things will make your URLs more friendly